# Android - how to find Intent for installed app(s)

Tags: android, android-intent

I know that an App (app2) I have installed on my device can be called from another App (app1). As app1 has a button that will bring up app2. Is there a way to determine what that Intent looks like to start app2 on my device? I want to modify my own app to do the same thing.

For example, this page on the Android Developers site shows you how to make implicit Intent calls for action.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending

But, is there a way to discover what Intents/Activities another App allows/makes-visible such that I can call app2 and open it?

Comment: How do you define "start app2"? Do you mean "do the same thing as if the user clicked on app2's icon in the launcher"?

Comment: Well, yes and no. App1 takes some contextual data and starts app2 with that data opened to the pertinent page. So, there is some data exchanged. Can I find out what key/value pairs it supports also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> App1 takes some contextual data and starts app2 with that data opened to the pertinent page

You are assuming that app2 has an activity supporting some `Intent` designed to do that.

> Is there a way to determine what that Intent looks like to start app2 on my device?

Talk to the developer of app2.

There are a number of common `Intent` structures (`ACTION_VIEW`, `ACTION_SEND`, etc.). Using `PackageManager`, you can find out if app2 supports one of those. Through a fair bit of complexity, there are ways that you can get to the manifest and find the `<intent-filter>` structures supported by any given app2 on a device.

If you are referring to *manually* examining app2 to see what it supports, there are [apps like this one](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.oF2pks.applicationsinfo/) that you can use.

> Can I find out what key/value pairs it supports also?

Talk to the developer of app2. That information is internal to the app and is not published in places like the manifest. If app2 happens to be open source, you can examine the source code.